# editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath does not get called using ViewDeck

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have been struggling for hours to add the swipe to delete feature to a plain `UITableView` in my app without success.

I have a `UIViewController` containing uniquely a `UITableView` which uses basic cells and custom cells. This `UIViewController` is on top of a `UINavigationController` which is the `centerViewController` of a [`IIViewDeckController`](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck)

The delegate and datasource of the `UITableView` are set properly and this is the current code :

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"canEditRowAtIndexPath");
    return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"commitEditingStyle");
}

-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath");
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath");
}
```

Other delegate methods like `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `canEditRowAtIndexPath`  and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` are called properly but `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` never gets called on any cell.

**Update**

When I do `[table setEditing:YES animated:YES];` it is indeed enabling the editing mode.

What could be missing here ?

Comment: Is it enabling edit mode when you do `[table setEditing:YES animated:YES];`?

Comment: Yes, it is enabling editing mode

Comment: Are you checking the swipe feature in device or simulator? also in editing mode, are you able to swipe and get the delete button? If you are checking in simulator, try in device because sometimes the swipe in simulator might be a bit difficult to do.

Comment: I'm checking the feature on a real device (iPhone 4S iOS 6) and Simulator. In editing mode I can see the delete icon on the left and when I tap on it then the delete button shows up but swiping still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the swipe event where caught by the `IIViewDeckController` in order to open the sidebar.

By setting the `IIViewDeckController` `panningMode` to `IIViewDeckNavigationBarPanning` it removes this feature and therefore fix the issue with the `UITableView`.

Comment: where do you set that `panningMode`for the `IIViewDeckNavigationBarPanning`?

Comment: When you instantiate your IIViewDeckController. IIViewDeckController* deckController = [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:self.navViewController leftViewController:leftMenuViewController];
    deckController.panningMode = IIViewDeckNavigationBarPanning;

Comment: You can take a look at the FeaturesExample in the GitHub: https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck/blob/master/FeaturesExample/ChoiceController.m